# Add constraint to mean square error cost function in multi output regression

Tags: python, optimization, machine-learning, keras, mean-square-error

I am using mean square error to compute the loss function of a multi output regressor. I used a recurrent neural network model with the one to many architecture. My output vector is of size 6 (1*6) and the values are monotonic (non decreasing).

example: 
y_i = [1,3,6,13,30,57,201]

I would like to force the model to learn this dependency. Hence adding a constraint to the cost function. I am getting an error equal to 300 on the validation set. I believe after editing the mean square error loss function i will be able to get a better performance.

I am using keras for the implementation. Here is the core model.

```
batchSize = 256
epochs = 20

samplesData = trainX
samplesLabels = trainY

print("Compiling neural network model...")

Model = Sequential()
Model.add(LSTM(input_shape = (98,),input_dim=98, output_dim=128, return_sequences=True))
Model.add(Dropout(0.2))
#Model.add(LSTM(128, return_sequences=True))
#Model.add(Dropout(0.2))
Model.add(TimeDistributedDense(7))  
#rmsprop = rmsprop(lr=0.0, decay=0.0)
Model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='rmsprop')
Model.summary()
print("Training model...")
# learning schedule callback
#lrate = LearningRateScheduler(step_decay)
#callbacks_list = [lrate]
history = Model.fit(samplesData, samplesLabels, batch_size=batchSize, nb_epoch= epochs, verbose=1,
                             validation_split=0.2, show_accuracy=True)
print("model training has been completed.")
```

Any other tips concerning learning rate, decay, etc.. are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Keep the mean squared error as just a metric. Use Smooth L1 loss instead. Here's my implementation.

```
#Define Smooth L1 Loss
def l1_smooth_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    abs_loss = tf.abs(y_true - y_pred)
    sq_loss = 0.5 * (y_true - y_pred)**2
    l1_loss = tf.where(tf.less(abs_loss, 1.0), sq_loss, abs_loss - 0.5)
    return tf.reduce_sum(l1_loss, -1)    
#And

Model.compile(loss='l1_smooth_loss', optimizer='rmsprop')
```